# Updated bdd since datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I develop at present for my company(society), a small program which allows the management of the hours of are workers, the management of construction sites(works) (addition, consultation, modifications) as well as one analytics of construction sites(works) and staff management in WPF (for information it is my first app in WPf, I have so far always to develop in WinForms).

The application is almost ended, however I come up against a small problem for the modification of a construction site(work).

I give some explanation:

I load(charge) in DataGrid by means of DataSet my table construction site(work) with the columns which I wants to be able to modify.

The xaml code of my DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="373" Margin="0,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="774" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=LoadDataBinding}" CanUserResizeRows="False" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="False" CellEditEnding="dataGrid_CellEditEnding" >
       <DataGrid.Columns>

           <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=numero}" Header="Numéro" IsReadOnly="True" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center"/>
           <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=responsable}" Header="Nom du responsable" IsReadOnly="True" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center"/>
           <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=description}" Header="Nom du chantier" IsReadOnly="True" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" />
           <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=zone}" Header="Zone" IsReadOnly="False" TextBlock.TextAlignment="Center" />

       </DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
           <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
               <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>

               <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
               <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />

           </Style>

       </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>


   </DataGrid>
```

Thus I bindé well and well put " IsReadOnly = "False" to accept the modification.

And here is the code C# to fill Datagrid:

```
public void selection_chantier(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       dataGrid.DataContext = trait.lire_chantier_par_numero(c_numero_chantier.SelectedItem.ToString());
   }
public DataSet lire_chantier_par_numero(string numero)
 {
     DataSet val = mbdd.table_lire("SELECT numero,responsable,description,zone FROM chantier WHERE numero = '"+numero+"'");
     return val;
 }
 public DataSet table_lire(string requete)
 {
 try
  {
     cn = new MySqlConnection();             //Création d'un nouvel objet cn
     cn.ConnectionString = con_Base;  //Requête de connexion
     cn.Open();
     da = new MySqlDataAdapter(requete, cn); //On crée un nouvel objet da      qui contiendra la requete et la connection
     ds = new DataSet(); //On crée un nouvel objet ds
     da.Fill(ds,"LoadDataBinding"); //On ajoute da dans le Dataset
     cn.Close(); //On se déconnecte de la mbdd
 }
 catch (MySqlException mySqlException)
 {
     MySqlException ex = mySqlException;
     System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Erreur suivante " + ex + " ");
     { return null; }
 }

 return ds; //On retourne le Dataset
 }
```

Thus my question is the following one, how is that at the moment or I modify a cell of DataGrid the modification records in my Bdd?

Thing which I know how to make with DataGridView of WinForm, but the I dries. I made tours of the forum, to ask has Google (my best friend when I have a concern;)) to consult MSDN, but Apparently I have of to miss something.

Edit: for the modification of cell I use the event: CellEditEnding

```
private void dataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
 {         
     trait.MajDataUtilisateur(ds);
    }
public void MajDataUtilisateur(DataSet ds)
    {
        mbdd.TableMaj(ds);
    }

public bool TableMaj(DataSet ds)
  {
      try
      {
          combuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da); //création du combuilder et indication du connecteur de données
          da.Fill(ds);
          da.Update(ds,"LoadDataBinding"); //on envoie le dataset ds vers le connecteur de données

          combuilder.Dispose(); //libération des ressources
          return true;
      }
      catch (MySqlException mySqlException)
      {
          MySqlException ex = mySqlException;
          //MessageBox.Show("Erreur suivante " + ex + " ");
          System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Erreur suivante " + ex + " ");

          return false;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well It could be more easy if you decide to use Entity Framework Model First, map your BD and save the entity the user modified with a few lines of code.

Always when I have this scenario I prefer to create a save button in each row, clicking this button will execute your code to save or edit the row.